# Cooking a Lean Cuisine frozen pizza in a toaster oven or regular oven instead of microwave

Tags: food-safety, food-science, pizza

I know it says in the directions to use microwave only. But I am more curious than anything else. Is it a food safety issue perhaps? I generally put olive oil around the crust of any frozen pizza to keep from burning and make it crisp.

I can try it no problem but maybe someone already has and know what will happen before I destroy three bucks.

Comment: Most frozen pizzas are supposed to be baked in a regular oven. You bought one which was specifically engineered to be microwaveable. I am curious - if you wanted to use a normal oven, why didn't you buy a standard frozen pizza meant for it?

Comment: I do ...my go to is  Amy's organic margarita. I slap olive oil on the crust and is arguably at least for me the best purchased pizza. It has no phosphate and all frozen pizza's do with this exception. But I recall using Nestles Lean Cuisine from back in the day and recall never having tried it baked with a little olive oil on it so I thought I would try. The directions specifically say "microwave only" and Nestle sticks to this because I called them and asked. I just wondered why and t thought someone might have tried it.

Answer (score 1):

First [google hit I found](https://www.goodnes.com/lean-cuisine/products/pepperoni-pizza/) said you can cook it either/or microwave or conventional oven.
I doubt a toaster oven is going to be much different, though you might have to watch out for it burning round the edges before the middle is completely done.

[image]

Comment: ...Sorry about that  last time I had one it said microwave only on the package maybe it changed??  I guess Nestle played the old musical directions on me and switched them. Those rascals

Comment: tbh, with pre-made pizzas with 'scone' base, as opposed to 'real' bread dough, all you're doing is heating it til the dough is cooked & the cheese melts. There's rarely anything even in the topping that would be hugely unsafe if slightly under-done. There's not going to be anything like raw meat in the topping.

Comment: Maybe something quirky about Lean Cuisine pizza?

Comment: I doubt it…  ;))

Comment: I will give it a try. I will destroy a pizza in the interest of food science and let you know if it works. I am treading where no pizza maker has gone before. It will be a few days though I have to get a fresh sample.